# using createElement to add a new paragraph to existing paragraph and keeping same css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript to add a new paragraph just below the existing paragraph on the html code page. The new paragraph is not following the same css as the first one. here is a link to the source code http://students.cpcc.edu/~lplumme2/web115/swtl/seventh10chaptersexamples.html

```js
function seventh10() {
    alert("let's start the javascipt");
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode("We have different ways of teaching you. Our office location is designed to look like a student lab.We can work with you one on one there or you can meet you somewhere else or we can even come to your house");
    para.appendChild(t);

    document.getElementById("myBlog").appendChild(para);
}

seventh10();
```

```html
<p id="myBlog">
    We have a variety of subjects and software that we can help you<br>
    improve your skills on. We teach from brand new levels to just helping<br>
    build on what you already know.<br>
</p>
```

Comment: can you add the css from your first paragraph? my thought is you have css around id myBlog, you could move that to a class and make your second paragrah use the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `p` element has some value set as *margin-left*. Since you are appending the the newly created `p` to another `p`, this `p` again taking the default *margin-left* set.

To fix the issue, you can set the *marginLeft* property to `0` for the newly created paragraph.

```
para.style.marginLeft = '0px';


function seventh10() {
  ....
  para.style.marginLeft = '0px';
  para.appendChild(t);
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code adds the new `<p>` *inside* the existing `<p>`.  That means that the left margin CSS rule applies for the second one with respect to the container `<p>` that's *also* got a big left margin.

To prevent that, you can add the new `<p>` to the element that contains the existing `<p>`.

Adding a `<p>` as a child of another `<p>` is kind-of unnatural anyway. The browser will let you manipulate the DOM pretty much any way you like, but the HTML parser won't do that. A `<p>` can't contain block content under HTML rules.